# Extract features from pretrained resnet50 in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, resnet

Hy guys, i want to extract the in_features of Fully connected layer of my pretrained resnet50.

I create before a method that give me the vector of features:

```
def get_vector(image):

#layer = model._modules.get('fc')

layer = model.fc
my_embedding = torch.zeros(2048) #2048 is the in_features of FC , output of avgpool

def copy_data(m, i, o):

    my_embedding.copy_(o.data)


h = layer.register_forward_hook(copy_data)
tmp = model(image)

h.remove()

# return the vector
return my_embedding
```

after I call this method here:

```
column = ["FlickrID", "Features"]

path = "./train_dataset/train_imgs/"

pathCSV = "./train_dataset/features/img_info_TRAIN.csv"



f_id=[]
features_extr=[]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=column)


tr=transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize(256),
                       transforms.CenterCrop(224),
                       transforms.ToTensor(),
                       transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])])



test = Dataset(path, pathCSV, transform=tr)

test_loader = DataLoader(test, batch_size=1, num_workers=2, shuffle = False)



#Leggiamo le immagini
for batch in test_loader:
    nome = batch['FlickrID']
    f_id.append(nome)
    image = batch['image']



    #print(image)
    with torch.no_grad():
        pred = get_vector(image)

    features_extr.append(pred)

df["FlickrID"] = f_id
df["Features"] = features_extr  


df.to_hdf("Places.h5", key='df', mode='w')
```

I have an error like this: 
output with shape [2048] doesn't match the broadcast shape [1, 2048, 1, 2048]

How can I take the in_feature of Fully Connected of this resnet50?
The Dataset is a customized Dataset class.

Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The model takes batched inputs, that means the input to the fully connected layer has size *[batch_size, 2048]*. Because you are using a batch size of 1, that becomes *[1, 2048]*. Therefore that doesn't fit into a the tensor `torch.zeros(2048)`, so it should be `torch.zeros(1, 2048)` instead.

You are also trying to use the output (`o`) of the layer `model.fc` instead of the input (`i`).

Besides that, using hooks is overly complicated for this and a much easier way to get features is to modify the model by replacing `model.fc` with [`nn.Identity`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Identity), which just returns the input as the output, and since the features are its input, the output of the entire model will be the features.

```py
model.fc = nn.Identity()

features = model(image)
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I don't think at simple solution. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me, works just as same as Michael's answer, effectively both are same

```
class EmptyModule(nn.Module) :
    def __init__(self, *args) :
        super(EmptyModule, self).__init__()
    def forward(self,x):
        return x

model.fc = EmptyModule()
```

Edit : NVM, nn.Identity() layer has the same code